# How to thin Chicken Alfredo sauce?

Tags: sauce, pasta, alfredo

I wanted to try something new with chicken breasts, came across Chicken Alfredo which seems pretty simple. However, the two times I've cooked Chicken Alfredo the sauce seems to come out rather thick and the pasta is glue-ey, but still very much edible.

I'd like to make the sauce thinner so that the pasta isn't sticking together as much. First thought that comes to mind is cook the sauce for less, but in all honesty it does look too watery to leave.

Here's my steps to making the sauce:

1. Medium/low heat
2. 2 Tbsp butter
3. 3 Finely chopped medium-sized garlic cloves. Wait until start of browning
4. Add 1 1/2 Tbsp plain flour
5. Keep stirring until garlic and flour become incorporated
6. Repeat steps 4 and 5
7. Immediately pour up to a glass of milk
8. Keep stirring and gradually add another glass of milk until sauce thickens
9. Keep stirring and finally turn off heat
10. Place cooked diced chicken into the pasta pan and stir.

I realise how thick the sauce gets in the last step, which may be due to the drop in pressure from multi-tasking :P. Can someone share some wisdom about sauce making, or even specifically Chicken Alfredo sauce making?

Answer (score 3):

The thickening agent in your recipe is flour. If you want to have thinner sauce then you need to add less flour when cooking the garlic. If a total of 6 to 7.5 Tbsp of flour is too much then maybe you should try adding a total of 4 Tbsp.

Comment: I'll try drop it from a total of 3 to 2 Tbsp of flour and report back.